# redis development: How do I add/enable debug messages when running unit tests

Tags: c, redis

I am adding a command to the redis code and when I run the unit test, I want to see the content of some of the data structures. I am running the test like this: `./runtest --single unit/acl`.  I have also added server log like this:

```
serverLog(LL_NOTICE, "This is called when the test is run");
```

However, I don't see this message printed on the screen. How do I add print statements and debug redis code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to execute `make` after modifying the source code.

You will not see serverLog() messages when you execute the test runner; they are from redis-server.

For test runs, redis-server logs are written to tests/tmp/<test-directory>/stdout.

---

Development cycle:

1. Edit source code
2. Write tests
3. Compile source code

   - `make`
4. Run tests

   - `./runtest` (add your arguments)
5. Inspect redis-server logs

   - `less tests/tmp/*/stdout`
6. Delete test artifacts

   - `rm -rf tests/tmp/*`

Comment: Thanks, I see the logs generated when I run `make test`. However, when I run ` ./runtest --single`, I don't see it. Any reason why?

Comment: Update your question with the output of `./runtest`. You should see a message that says `Starting test server at port <port>` unless you turned on the `--quiet` option.